# Initializing a shadowing variable

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is there anything in the standard that defines initialing a variable from the variable it shadows?

For example:

```
int i = 7;
{
    int i = i;
}
```

Visual Studio 2013 allows this without a warning and works as expected. The inner `i` variable is 7. Clang and GCC however give me a warning about a initializing variable initializing from itself will be uninitialized.

Comment: My copy of VS2013 says `error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'i' used`

Comment: @NtscCobalt Perhaps you have your warning level set too low?

Comment: @YoungJohn I was substituting a class with `int` to simplify the question which is why I didn't see the warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard has this to say:

> **3.3.2** Point of declaration **[basic.scope.pdecl]**
>
> **1** The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its complete declarator
>   (Clause 8) and before its *initializer* (if any), except as noted below.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> int x = 12;
> { int x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second x is initialized
>   with its own (indeterminate) value. —end example ]

This is precisely your case. The program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized object.

My copy of VS2013 reports `error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'i' used` for this code. Not sure why your copy behaves differently.

Comment: The type of `i` is actually a class without a ctor in my code which is why I didn't see the warning. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If the first variable is defined in a namespace for example in the global namespace then you can write using its qualified name

```
int i = 7;

int main()
{
   int i = ::i;
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to provide a work-a-round. In this case though they are more like while/for scopes I need these in. If I was able to use C++11 I'd just replace them with lambdas but alas my work needs to target some pretty old compilers.