# cin as a variable name producing garbage value

Tags: c++, namespaces, keyword

For the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
       int cin;
       cin >> cin;
       cout << "cin : " << cin;
       return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be:

```
cin : <input>
```

But the output is:

```
cin : <junk value>
```

Comment: That is why you shouldn't use: `using namespace std;`

Comment: Your example does not compile. Please provide a minimal compilable example, with headers, any using statements, a question, and why you expect the output to be what you expect it to be.

Comment: It's the same as `int x; x >> x; cout << x;`, which makes no sense. On the other hand, `std::cin >> cin` would work.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz It actually [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/s4aWU4)

Comment: this question should be upvoted and kept as a reference to why one should never ever be `using namespace std;`

Comment: Thank you everyone. I got it.

Comment: why people are down voting the question? Did i ask something so silly?

Comment: I didn't vote on this question either way. I don't agree with the downvotes. But I believe the question would be better asked if the full program with the headers and using statements was included. Also, some demonstration of research effort would defang potential downvotes.

Comment: @ShivamArora please include your full program so we have the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without that any answer is speculation

Comment: @christopher Widen your dishes horizon!

Comment: I have updated the code. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I really cannot understand the extremely low score on this. It's an excellent question. Even without those extra lines needed to compile it's a pretty good question.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27528453/332733) and [directly related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25576495/332733)

Comment: I updated my question, still the down vote count is increasing. If it is too bad to be a question please vote it to be deleted. I am unable to do so from my end.

Comment: @ShivamArora Upvotes are coming ... No need for deletion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : Thanks for your time and helping me out.

Comment: @Rama, removing namespace didn't do anything though, I tried it in an online editor and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK let's dissect your code  (`using namespace std` assumed):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
       int cin; // Shadows the declaration of cin coming from the iostream header
       cin >> cin; // A bit shift operation on variable cin without capturing the result
       cout << "cin" << cin; // Output of the non initialized variable cin
       return 0;
}
```

[Kinda proof](http://ideone.com/s4aWU4)

Comment: can you please explain a bit more where I can land into trouble using **using namespace std;**

Comment: @ShivamArora Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @ShivamArora People are guessing that you think `cin` in `cin >>` refers to `std::cin`.

Comment: How are you answering anything when there is no question? And why are you providing code that does not compile? cout is no qualified with std:: and you did no include <iostream> On any C++11 capable compiler, the output Is 'cout' : undeclared identifier.

Comment: @ShivamArora does this really not convince you? This is the farthest into land of trouble I ever saw someone getting with using namespace std

Comment: @tobi303 What if OP's real code doesn't have `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @juanchopanza its the only way i can imagine to get the result OP is reporting.... wait no...you are completely right. I am 99% certain that the original code has a using namespace, but yes, unless OP fixes his post there is no point in making assumptions.

Comment: @tobi303 How about `using std::cin;`?

Comment: @juanchopanza then it would not compile, unless it also had a `using std::cout`, but really you dont have to convince me. The OP misses a mcve and cannot be answered properly as is. And actually even if it had a `using namespace std;` the bad thing about it is a bad choice of variable names and the using issue is just secondary imho

Comment: @tobi303 Local scope 1st, as always.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you should probably mention that the local `cin` is shadowing the global `cin`

Comment: @Mgetz Done so.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I dont want to join a pointless fight, but I saw the original answer before any edits and it had a note saying that it assumes that there is a `using namespace std;`. I agree that the question should first be improved before it can be answered properly, but I think you are overreacting a bit

Answer (score 6):

Ok, that is your opportunity to join the white side of the force and stop using `using namespace std;`

The following example works fine for `int` inputs:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
       int cin;
       std::cin >> cin;
       std::cout << "cin: " << cin;
       return 0;
}
```

Why? In your example your local name `int cin` will take preference over `cin` from `std` and cause your program have UB using an `int` variable without initializing.

And a good advise, but offtopic could be to test the result of `std::cin::operator >>` with the failbit like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395801/how-is-stdcinvalue-evaluated-in-a-while-loop)

Comment: Thank you Rama. I don't know why people are down voting anyways thanks for your valuable time

Comment: its a fix, but doesnt really explain why OPs code produces the output it does

Comment: @ShivamArora Your question is being downvoted because its not a very good question. Yes, it is a question, but its such a basic question that you could pick up a basic C++ book, read the first chapter, and figure out what your problem is. You showed that you did not do any research nor understand what you wrote.

Comment: @tobi303 Thanks!, added explanation

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Thanks, Added an advise regarding to failbit check